# Windows: command line how to unzip file and rename it's content with zipped file name in current folder and sub folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would appreciate if I got help on this, I have the following script that unzip and rename the content with zipped file name, however it works in the current folder only,  I need it work in subfolders as well!

```
@Echo off
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b  *.zip *.rar') DO (
     "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
    for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir  /b *.html') do (
        ren "%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    ) 
)
```

it should search for any .zip file and unzip it and rename it's content with the zip file, example:

abc.zip ---> contains xyz.html

the result should be ----> abc.html

Comment: `dir  /b /s /a-d *.html` and change `ren "%%f" "%%~nI.html"` to `ren "%%~f" "%%~nI.html"`

Comment: @Gerhard, it doesn't make any effect, it just work like the original one. I need it to affect the subfolder, but it doesn't

Comment: if I add (dir  /b /s /a-d *.zip ) in the first For, it work in subfolders, but it renames all the extracted .html file with the most inner .zip file name and this name is reflected to extracted .html in parent directories as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around, it's not the best but solve the issue, you need to create a script that target the desired directory and run other script that works in the current directory only.

script target desired dircotry:

```
cd /D D:\Target\
Call C:\Scripts\UnzipRenameScript.cmd
```

and here the script that do the work (UnzipRenameScript):

```
@Echo off
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b  *.zip *.rar') DO (
    del "%%~nI.html"
     "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
    for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir  /b *.html') do (
        ren "%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    del "%%~nI.zip"
    ) 
)
```